# JAVASCRIPT: OK button proceed to another .php form

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms

I have a basic javascript code for my saving entry.

**Scenario:**

I have two forms, the first form,[view_netbldg.php], is for my data entry then when the user click the *"ADD"* button it will proceed to the next form [save_netbldg.php]. So in my save_netbldg.php form there is a if else condition where the code will know first if the variable of $bldgName or $netName are empty. Everything is okay, but my concern is this when the code detect either of the two variables are empty the code below I'm using will be executed.

Here's my code:

```
if($bldgName == "" || $netName == "")
{
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>\n";
echo "alert('Please complete the fields for Building Name or Network Name');\n";
echo "</script>";
header("location:view_netbdlg.php");
}
```

*The result of the program is, its not displaying the *alert* instead it will jump to the *header*

The correct way is, if the ***$bldgName == "" || $netName == ""*** == true** an *alert* will display and when the user click the *ok button* it will proceed to the next form which is "view_netbdlg.php". I don't need a confirmation message here because its only an error message something like that.

Advance thank you.

Comment: Why not check it in javascript and after that proceed to `PHP` file if no error is there.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar...there is no error...When I add the "Header" its not displaying the alert

Comment: Don't set the header in PHP - it will jum to the next page before your javascript executes. Instead use Javascript to change the page once the `alert` has been cleared. `document.location.href = newUrl;

` in your javascript shoud do it.

Comment: users with js will just fall through so you might want to have a `noscript` message!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing php with javascript, You can solve this by

```
if($bldgName == "" || $netName == "")
{
 echo "<script type='text/javascript'>\n";
 echo "alert('Please complete the fields for Building Name or Network Name');\n";
 echo "window.location='view_netbdlg.php';\n";
 echo "</script>";
}
```

Comment: @DuyLuc.... I changed your code of "echo "window.location='location:view_netbdlg.php';\n";" TO "echo "window.location='view_netbldg.php'"; because its getting an error saying that "The address wasn't understood".. if its okay to you can you edit that code only..And Its working,.. thank you

Comment: just to tell you non js users won't see the alert or be redirected. If  going this path add a `<noscript>` with a link to the page

Answer (score 1):

That happens because when the document loads, it stops when it finds a script tag.

In your case, you're trying to echo data in an undetermined part of the document, when it is already loaded.

Here's my solution:

PHP File (test.php):

```
<?php
    if(!isset($_POST['bldgName']) || !isset($_POST['netName']) {
        die("false"); //returns false if the values are NOT set
    } else {
        die("true"); //returns true if the values are set
    }
?>
```

In your file (file.html):

```
<form method="post" action="test.php" id="formtest">
    <input type="text" name="bldgName" />
    <input type="text" name="netName" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
if(getAjaxResponse(document.getElementById("formtest") == "true") {
    alert("Please complete the fields for Building Name or Network Name");
    window.navigate("view_netbdlg.php");
}
function getAjaxResponse(frm){
var elem = frm.elements;
var params = "";
url = form.action;
for(var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++){
    if (elem[i].tagName == "SELECT"){
        params += elem[i].name + "=" + encodeURIComponent(elem[i].options[elem[i].selectedIndex].value) + "&";
    } else {
        params += elem[i].name + "=" + encodeURIComponent(elem[i].value) + "&";
    }
} 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.open("POST",url,false);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
xmlhttp.send(params);
return xmlhttp.responseText;    
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
if($bldgName == "" || $netName == ""){
    header('Refresh: 10; URL=your url');#10 second delay
    echo "Please complete the fields for Building Name or Network Name";
    exit;#make sure rest of page doesn't render!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have written the the code under script and never invoked that script
for that you have to use functions and call the function manually...

For more about function call refer

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Call